# Firefox CSS Specific Syntax

Tags: css

I have a header that is aligned differently in Chrome vs Firefox. I am using padding to align, but I want different CSS syntax for Chrome vs Firefox. I added this to my css file, but it didn't work:

@-moz-document url-prefix() { .header-col-flex { padding: 0em .1em .2em 5.3em; } }

For chrome, I want this syntax to display:

padding: 1em .1em .2em 5.3em;

For Firefox, I want it to syntax to display:

padding: 0em .1em .2em 5.3em;

Can anyone advise?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? I'm pretty sure this can be resolved without resorting to hacks like that.

Comment: By the way, the `url-prefix` function expects an url. For instance, `@-moz-document url-prefix(http://www.w3.org/Style/)`